# Validate Entity Framework object in ViewModel from wpf client side

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, validation, mvvm-light

In my WPF MVVM-Light ViewModel class I have a property, that is an EntityObject from EntityFramework 6

```
    public Client Client
    {
        get { return client; }
        set
        {
            client = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Client);
        }
    }
```

Partial part of the Client class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ClientMetadata))]
[CustomValidation(typeof(ClientValidator), "ClientValidation")]
public partial class Client
{
    public sealed class ClientMetadata
    {
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(CaptionResources), Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It's binded to many controls in the view, like:

```
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5" Height="36" Text="{Binding Client.Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" TabIndex="1"
                     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ImagedErrorTemplate}"/>
```

How can I display the validation result on the view? I already have `INotifyDataErrorInfo, IValidationErrors` interfaces implemented in my ViewModel. I already have a method that validates the object and returns validation errors:

```
    private bool Validate()
    {
        var errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (!IsValid<Client, Client.ClientMetadata>(this.Client, ref errors))
        {
            foreach (var error in errors)
            {

                this.RaiseErrorsChanged("Client." + error.Key);
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(string.Format("Client.{0}", error.Key));
            }

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

But I still can't get this information in the view. My error template works for "standard" properties:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ImagedErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel >
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner"/>
        </Border>
        <Image Source="../Assets/Images/warning.png" 
                            Height="20" 
                            Width="20"
                            ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Is there any way to do that without DTO objects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need a textblock in the control template for your error to display the error message?

Comment: It doesn't make difference. I want to make validation for most of controls, not only textblock.

Comment: I didn't mean that, what i meant is your control template needs to display some text when error occurs using a text block. NOT validate only for text block. Hope this makes sense

Comment: It works for standard ViewModel properties. The error message is displayed in ToolTip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do it by implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo on EntityFramework objects.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ClientMetadata))]
[CustomValidation(typeof(ClientValidator), "ClientValidation")]
public partial class Client : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>> validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>>();

    public sealed class ClientMetadata
    {
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(CaptionResources), Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>> ValidationErrors
    {
        get
        {
            return this.validationErrors;
        }
        set
        {
            this.validationErrors = value;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || !this.ValidationErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return this.ValidationErrors[propertyName];
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get { return this.ValidationErrors.Count > 0; }
    }

    public void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.ErrorsChanged != null)
        {
            this.ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```